# Changing drupal view filter from greater than to less than

Tags: php, drupal, view

I have a drupal view I've created for events, each event has a date field I'd like to create a way either in the view itself or via the API to have an option for users to select all events, past events or future events. I've created a basic filter event_date > now which works, however I can't seem to change this to event_date < now via the views API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a module for that.
Acces the api and use it.
You should see this pages also:

```
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_filter/6

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_elements/6

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/6

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_action_info/6

function theme_test_form($form) {
  $output = '';
  $output .= drupal_render($form['name']);
  $output .= '<div class="foo">';
  $output .= drupal_render($form['access']);
  $output .= '<div class="bar">';
  $output .= drupal_render($form['details']);
  $output .= '</div></div>';
  $output .= drupal_render($form);
  return $output;
```